# Differential Equation: Finding the general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the differential equation:
> $$(D-2)^2(D+1)y=\exp(-x)$$
> Give the general solution of the above equation.

My first impression of this question is that it is not the differential equation format but to be able to solve, don't we need to have $\dfrac{\text dy}{\text dx}$ but I don't see any of this.

Can someone please help me because this question is part of an exam paper and I have never seen such type of question?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Use MathJax formatting for mathematical expressions. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

$D$ represents $\frac{d}{dx}$, thus $Dy$ would represent $\frac{dy}{dx}$
$$(D-2)^2(D+1)y=e^{-x}$$
$$(D^2-4D+4)(D+1)y=e^{-x}$$
$$(D^3-3D^2+4)y=e^{-x}$$

Complementary function:
$$(m-2)^2(m+1)=0$$
$$m=2,2,-1$$
$$y_c=(c_1+c_2x)e^{2x}+c_3e^{-x}$$

Particular integral:
$$y_p=\frac{e^{-x}}{D^3-3D^2+4}$$

Substituting $-1$ in place of D in the expression in the denominator would yield $0$, and hence $y_p$ would be indeterminate. Hence:
$$y_p=\frac{xe^{-x}}{3D^2-6D}$$
$$y_p=\frac{xe^{-x}}{9}$$

Therefore, the entire solution would be:
$$y=y_c+y_p$$
$$y= (c_1+c_2x)e^{2x}+c_3e^{-x}+\frac{xe^{-x}}{9}$$

[Check this out to know more about the method used](http://www.mathematics.me.uk/tutorials/Solving%20ODEs%20by%20Complementary%20Function%20and%20%20Particular%20Integral.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.Very grateful

Comment: @danisha    No problem!! Kindly upvote, or accept the answer if you found my explanation satisfactory...

Answer (score 0):

## If an exam question confuses you, don't ask random people on the internet, contact your instructor.

With that said, $D$ here almost certainly represents the differential operator $\frac{d}{dx}$.  So they want you to solve $$\left(\frac{d}{dx}-2\right)^2\left(\frac{d}{dx}+1\right)y=e^{-x}$$  I won't simplify further, because that is likely a skill the exam is testing you on.

This ODE is linear, so the solution method is standard.  First characterize the homogenous solutions (i.e. replace the RHS with $0$).  Then consider a family of functions similar to your forcing and try to find a member of that family that solve the inhomogenous equation.

Comment: Thank you  and I am taking your advice but unfortunately, the instructor has been changed and we are expected to learn the materials on our own.

Answer (score 0):

$(D-2)^2D$ is the factored form of the operator $D^3-4D^2+4D,$ where $D$ is $d\over dx$.
The solution to $(D-2)^2Dy=0$ is $c_1e^{2x}+c_2xe^{2x}+c_3.$
Find $k$ so that $(D-2)^2D(ke^{-x})=e^{-x}$ by evaluating $(D-2)^2D(e^{-x}).$

Comment: I thought I saw D and not (D+1) on the right when I answered the question.

Comment: Its okay. Thanks for your solution

Comment: One question why has you introduced the unknown k

Comment: To get a particular solution to the original differential equation. When you calculate $(D-2)^2D(e^{-x}),$ you'll get (constant) times $e^{-x}.$ Then $k$ is the reciprocal of this constant.